# Allowed transformations in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor

So in Special Relativity we have: $$ \Lambda \eta \Lambda^T=\eta $$

Is there an analagous formula for the metric in General Relativity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group Theory in General Relativity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65688/)

Comment: Hi, I saw that post. I see that the the symmetry group is either Diff(2) or GL(R,4) depending on whom you ask. I didn't see an answer to this part of the original question, though.