# Constructing Killing tensors from Killing vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

**Background:**

After reading about [Carter constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carter_constant) and [symmetries in GR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65688/), I became interested in [Killing tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_tensor).

I tried reading [this paper](http://cds.cern.ch/record/594922/files/0212016.pdf) by Alan Barnes, Brian Edgar and Raffaele Rani, discussing conformal Killing tensors. I have some trouble understanding the crux of the paper.

**Question:**

- Is there a general way to construct Killing tensors, if the Killing vectors are known?
- How would I do this?
- Are there any Killing tensors that can not be constructed from Killing vectors?

**Initial guess/motivation for the question:**

Initially, I thought Killing tensors could just be formed via $K_{\mu \nu}=k_\mu k'_\nu$, where $K_{\mu \nu}$=Killing tensor, $k_\mu,k'_\nu$=Killing vectors. After reading the above paper, I am no longer sure. The paper discusses *conformal* Killing tensors and vectors, which may be the source of my confusion.

Comment: I'm now re-reading the article in hopes of learning a bit more.

Comment: **This is a short answer**

But basically Killing tensors can be constructed at least via:

$K_{\mu \nu}=k_\mu k_\nu$

This satisfies the Killing tensor equation:

$K_{(\mu \nu;c)}=0$

Just by using the Killing vector equation: $k_{(\mu;c)}=0$

Answer (score 1):

Killing tensors created by just product of two Killing vectors is only in the trivial case. In a non-trivial case this is not possible such as in finding the Carter constants. This is all I know as I'm also a beginner.